# Can you assign custom icons to file types that don't have icons yet?

Tags: visual-studio-code, icons, customization

I want to assign an icon to `.vert`-files. Now they have the same icon as textiles, so there is no icon assigned to it yet. Is it possible to assign an icon to this file-extension and if yes, how?